# Gradle - ear task

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, gradle

I was trying to use 'appDirName'in ear task, which has '**META-INF**/application.xml'
When it is creating ear file, it is creating with '**meta-inf**/application.xml'.
Ear file is not deployable to Websphere 6.1. application server.
Please suggest.

Messsages from WAS 6.1:

> The EAR file could be corrupt and/or incomplete. Make sure that the application is at a compatible Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition (J2EE) Level for WebSphere Application Server.
>
> AppDeploymentException: [null] org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/application.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of version do you create? I believe WebSphere 6.1 is J2EE 1.4, but gradle ear-plugin assumes version 6. I had that problem with Weblogic, however it was more verbose. See http://www.gradle.org/ear_plugin.html on how to alter ear-plugin:

```
ear {
  deploymentDescriptor {
    version = '1.4'
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is JEE 1.4 and it requires the jars to be in the root of EAR file. Gradle creates **lib** directory and keep all jars into that. I figured it out to keep it in the root by using **libDirName** empty. It works now.